# How do I iterate through error returned by Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a model which looks something like this:

**User.js**

```
var AuthorSchema = Schema({
    first_name: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 20},
    last_name: {type: String, minlength: 5, maxlength: 20},
    username: {type: String, required: true, match: /([0-9A-Za-z]){5,20}/},
    password: String,
    email: {type: String, required: true,

        validate: function(email) {
            return /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/.test(email)
        }

    },
    createdOn: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updatedOn: {type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

**app.js**

```
a = new my_models.Author({
     first_name: 'err',  ## invalid
     username: 'tim001@',  # invalid
     password: 'pass',
     email: 'aaa',  # invalid
});

a.save(function (err) {
    if(err) { console.log(err) return; }
    console.log("Author saved")
});
```

How to iternate though errors object returned by mongoose ?

Comment: The object is returning one error, not many. One save operation can give you at most one error.

Comment: I am passing invalid data to three fields and I want to know how do I iterate through those errors.

Comment: Look at the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html), `err.errors` gives you an object that each key is a field that didn't pass validation. If you question is how to iterate over that object, it's just using plain javascript and has nothing to do with mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

You can check validation before saving the data. Try something like this

```
const a = new my_models.Author({ first_name: 'err', username: 'tim001@', password: 'pass', email: 'aaa', });
const validateResult = a.validateSync(); 
const {message} = validateResult.errors.name;
console.log(message);
```